# Using the id attribute of a select to process JSON data in jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I am dealing with several dynamically updating select boxes, much like a auto website that dynamically updates make, model, etc. Early in my script I identify the changing select, then identify the next select and pull its id from the page like so:

```
var next_select_id = $(next_select).attr('id');
```

I call it `next_select_id` because the HTML ID of any given select corresponds to the parent object type in the JSON response.

In the case of two selects with the ids "A" and "B", upon changing A, `next_select_id` should be "B". This works later in the page where I generate a URL by concatenating `next_select_id` with strings (For example, it generates `http://testing.com/users/B` just fine).

Later on when I attempt to process a JSON file with a parent key based on `next_select_id` containing names and id values this way:

```
$.each(data, function(i, j){  
  row = "<option value=\"" + j.next_select_id.id + "\">" + j.next_select_id.name + "</option>";  
  $(row).appendTo(next_select);                     
});
```

The `j.something.id` in this case corresponding to the ID of an ActiveRecord object.

It says "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined". Do I need to be converting `next_select_id` in some way before attempting this? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was a bit confused about the proper way to use my string assigned to a variable. In the end, the fix was a simple notational change to:

```
j[next_select_id]["name"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already set next_select_id to the ID string. Just remove your extra .id in that $.each and it should work. (If not, please post the code where you set next_select_id for the $.each.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I was a bit scattered. What I'm basically asking is if my var next_select_id = $(next_select).attr('id'); stores, say, "B", why does "A" + B + "C" produce "ABC" in my script while j.next_select_id.id does not produce j.B.id. I feel like I should somehow be converting next_string_id before attempting to use it in the each function.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant "A" + next_select_id + "C" produces "ABC".